# Jprofiler session filter settings to avoid tracing of jdk calls

Tags: jprofiler

Hi could you please let me know the session filter setting to be added in jprofiler to prevent tracing of jdk internal calls?

Answer (score 0):

Internal calls in the java.* packages are not measured by JProfiler in any case, regardless of your filter settings.

If you define "inclusive" filters that define the profiled classes, then all other packages are not profiled.

Note that the first call from a profiled class into a non-profiled class is always shown in the call tree, it's just the further internal calls that are not measured.